# closed immersion in $\mathbb{A}_A^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring, $X$ an $A$-scheme. The scheme $X$ is told projective if there is some closed immersion $X\to\mathbb{P}_A^n$ over $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$. For proper schemes these embeddings are described by the ample invertible sheaves which gives multiple possible embeddings. Why is there not equivalent definition for the affine case?

I mean for $A$-scheme with some closed immersion $X\to\mathbb{A}_A^n
$. I guess for this case it's trivial but can't see why (or the affines made it the things more difficult?). Can't wee have multiple possible closed immersions? These immersions give $X\simeq\mathrm{Spec}(A[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I)$ so we should have $A[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I\simeq A[x_1,\ldots,x_k]/J$. We cannot conclude that $n=k$ and $I=J$ because we can add superfluous variables $A[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I\simeq A[x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}]/(I+(x_{n+1}))$ but appart from that is there some easy description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since any closed subscheme of an affine scheme is affine, a scheme which admits a closed embedding in to $\Bbb A^n_A$ is again affine. Thus your $X$ is the spectrum of some ring $R$, and the closed immersion $X\to \Bbb A^n_A$ is given by a surjective morphism of rings $A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to R$. This means that closed immersions in to affine space over $A$ are in bijection with (ordered) generating sets of $R$ as an $A$-algebra.

Comment: I guess that this is eaiser in this case because for projective spaces the global sections (ie elements of $R$) are not sufficients but one has to take elements of invertible sheaves $\mathcal{L}$ that generate the sheaf?